# MongoDB: Reference another document with additional info attached

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a situation where I have a type of group document.  I want to have a list field that contains a reference Id to the users in the group.  I need to however indicate which users have admin access.  Should I have two lists, one of regular users and one of admins, or have a custom document that I embed a list of that just has the reference Id and a bool value?  This is basically a many to many, with both documents have a list of reference Ids to the other documents.  I'm just not sure how to include this other value.

If it makes any difference I'm using Python/Mongoengine to access the MongoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways of modelling your requirement in the current form. I'll try to show you one such way and uses ***[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)***. You should try with two separate collections one for each groups and users like below.

One other option will be to use ***[$DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references)*** which will eagerly load all the users in the group when you fetch group collection. This option will depend on python driver and I'm sure driver supports that.

**Groups Document**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5857e7d5aceaaa5d2254aea2"),
    "name": "newGroup",
    "usersId": ["user1", "user2"]
}
```

**Users Document**

```
{ "_id" : "user1", "isAdmin" : true }
{ "_id" : "user2" }
```

**Get All Users in a group**

```
db.groups.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$usersId'
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "usersId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "group_users"
    }
})
```

**Response**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5857e7d5aceaaa5d2254aea2"),
    "name": "newGroup",
    "usersId": "user1",
    "group_users": [{
        "_id": "user1",
        "isAdmin": true
    }]
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("5857e7d5aceaaa5d2254aea2"),
    "name": "newGroup",
    "usersId": "user2",
    "group_users": [{
        "_id": "user2"
    }]
}
```

**Get All Admin Users in a group**

```
db.groups.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$usersId'
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "usersId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "group_users"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "group_users.isAdmin": {
            $exists: true
        }
    }
})
```

**Response**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5857e7d5aceaaa5d2254aea2"),
    "name": "newGroup",
    "usersId": "user1",
    "group_users": [{
        "_id": "user1",
        "isAdmin": true
    }]
}
```

Based on comment:

> The is admin is admin for the group, so I can't store it in the users
>   table.  This is a many to many relationship.

I think you should include both the regular users list and admin users list. This will use the indexes you add and will make your read queries really straight forward.

**Groups Document**

```
{ "_id" : "newGroup", "userIds" : [ "user1" ], "adminIds" : [ "user2" ] }
```

**Users Document**

```
{ "_id" : "user1", "groupIds" : [ "newGroup" ] } -- regular user in newGroup
{ "_id" : "user2", "groupIds" : [ "newGroup" ] } -- admin user in newGroup.
{ "_id" : "user3", "groupIds" : [ ] }
```

**Get All Regular Users**

```
db.groups.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$userIds'
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "userIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "group_users"
    }
})
```

**Get All Admin Users**

```
db.groups.aggregate({
    $unwind: '$adminIds'
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "adminIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "group_users"
    }
})
```

Comment: The is admin is admin for the group, so I can't store it in the users table.  This is a many to many relationship.

Comment: Couple of questions here. Many to Many meaning the user knows which group he is part of meaning you will have a list of groups in each user document ? Other question How do you pick a user as a admin ? Is that something you assign some users as admin for each group when you create a group ? Updated answer based on this comment.

Comment: So this app has various locations.  Users have access to the locations they are attached to.  Admins at each locations have permissions to edit that location.  A user can be attached to many groups, and a group has many users.  Some users of each group will be admins.  So in other instances of many to many I have seen them use a list of users in the group and a list of groups for each user.  I need to do that, but also indicate if you're an admin as well.

Comment: If this were a sql db I would have my join table with the user id and location id, but also a boolean value to indicate admin.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the updated answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: So basically have two lists, one for regular groups and one where you're an admin.